# when i click on update button i want the course open in add course with the same values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

following is the AddCourse page
AddCourse.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText, Container } from 'reactstrap';
import database from '../services/fire';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import uuid from 'react-uuid';
import '../App.css';

const AddCourse = () => {

    const [courseId, setCourseId] = useState('');
    const [courseTitle, setCourseTitle] = useState('');
    const [courseDesc, setCourseDesc] = useState('');
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user.uid);

    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = "Add Courses"
    }, [])

    const addCourse = () => {
        const payload = { id: uuid(), courseId:courseId, courseTitle: courseTitle, courseDesc: courseDesc }
        const dbcoursesWrapper = database.ref().child(user).child('courses');
        // const dbcoursesWrapper = database.ref(`users/${user}/courses`).push(courseId, courseTitle, setCourseDesc);
        return dbcoursesWrapper.child(payload.id).update(payload).then(() => {
            setCourseId('');
            setCourseTitle('');
            setCourseDesc('');
            dispatch({ type: "ADD_COURSES", payload });
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="text-center my-3">Fill Course Detail</h1>
            <Form onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault(e.target.value);
                addCourse();
            }}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <label for="UserId">Course Id</label>
                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        value={courseId}
                        onChange={(e) => setCourseId(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Enter your Id"
                        name="userId"
                        id="UserId"
                    />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                    <label for="title">Course Title</label>
                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        value={courseTitle}
                        onChange={(e)=> setCourseTitle(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Enter Course Title"
                        name="title"
                        id="title"
                    />
                </FormGroup>

                <label for="description">Course Description</label>
                <Input
                    value={courseDesc}
                    onChange={(e) => setCourseDesc(e.target.value)}
                    type="textarea"
                    placeholder="Enter Course Description"
                    name="description"
                    id="description"
                    style={{ height: 150 }}
                />
                <Container className="text-center">
                    <Button color="success" type='submit'>Add Course</Button>
                    <Button color="warning ml-3">clear</Button>
                </Container>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
};
export default AddCourse;
```

courses.js here is the update button when i click on it i want it to open the AddCourse page with the same values of the course i want to update not getting any clue how can i do this

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Card, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle,  Button, Container
} from 'reactstrap';
import database from '../services/fire';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchCourse } from '../actions/courses';
import AddCourse from './AddCourse';

const Course = ({course}) => {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user.uid);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const removeCourse = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    const dbtasksWrapper = database.ref().child(user).child('courses');
    dbtasksWrapper.child(id).remove().then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_COURSE', id: id })
        dispatch(fetchCourse(user));
    })  
  }
  
  
    return (
        <div>
          <Card>
            <CardBody className="text-center ">
            <CardText className="text-center"><h2>CourseID: {course.courseId}</h2></CardText>
              <CardTitle className="font-weight-bold text-center"><h1>{course.courseTitle}</h1></CardTitle>
              <CardText className="text-center">{course.courseDesc}.</CardText>
              <Container className="text-center">
              {/* here is the update button and when onclick its goes to add course page with the course vale need to update**  */}
              <Button color="warning"onClick={}>Update</Button>
              <Button color="danger ml-4" onClick={()=>removeCourse(course.id)}>Delete</Button>
              </Container>

            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    };
export default Course;
```

Comment: Your formatting is a bit broken, can you double-check and edit the question to provide the appropriate code?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not getting your question properly. You are trying to add a course using `AddCourse.js component` on submitting the form, then you want to display the course ID, Title and Description. In order to do this, you need the following:
1 - localStorage,
2 - Context API or Redux,
3 - Create a new state on your Context API or redux to store the values and pass it down to children components, in your example courses.js

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to switch between viewing a course and editing/updating a course?

One way to achieve this is:

```
const Course = ({ course }) => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user.uid);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const removeCourse = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    const dbtasksWrapper = database.ref().child(user).child('courses');
    dbtasksWrapper
      .child(id)
      .remove()
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_COURSE', id });
        dispatch(fetchCourse(user));
      });
  };

  // state to switch between updating the course and viewing the course
  const [isUpdating, setIsUpdating] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {isUpdating ? (
        {/* pass the course down and a callback to close update component  */}
        <AddCourse course={course} finishUpdate={() => setIsUpdating(false)} />
      ) : (
        <Card>
          <CardBody className="text-center ">
            <CardText className="text-center">
              <h2>CourseID: {course.courseId}</h2>
            </CardText>
            <CardTitle className="font-weight-bold text-center">
              <h1>{course.courseTitle}</h1>
            </CardTitle>
            <CardText className="text-center">{course.courseDesc}.</CardText>
            <Container className="text-center">
              {/* Set isUpdating to true */}
              <Button color="warning" onClick={() => setIsUpdating(true)}>
                Update
              </Button>
              <Button color="danger ml-4" onClick={() => removeCourse(course.id)}>
                Delete
              </Button>
            </Container>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This will change depending on your setup, if this isn't what you wanted please provide some more details about how you would like this to function.

Comment: @jzee sorry there was a typo `onClick={() => setIsUpdating(true)}` have corrected now

Comment: thanks now what happen when I update the course its and made changes its add another course instead of changing that course i think <AddCourse course = {course} need to edit well i am looking into this